# urllib module errors launching script with python 2.7.13

Tags: python-2.7, urllib

i want to launch a script to get a file by url with urllib but I always get a sequence of errors:
[image]

I checked the documentation and says that something is deprecated but i can't find the right syntax.

```
import urllib

fhand = urllib.urlopen('http://www-dr-chuck.com/page1.htm')
for line in fhand:
    print line.strip()
```

Comment: Please put the code for which you are getting that error.

Comment: I edited the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your URL is wrong.

> http://www-dr-chuck.com/page1.htm

I think it should be

> http://www.dr-chuck.com/page1.htm

There should be a dot `.` after www not a dash `-`.

Comment: Ohh! I'm so ... I don't want to put any ugly word! Thank you so much! I must be more care of that.